# Image GDI+ Error c#

Tags: c#, winforms, image

First sorry for the english. I'm having an strange problem when I'm trying to save a bitmap ("Generic GDI+ error") from a picturebox in my win app, I know that this problem occurs when trying to save to a directory that has no permission, but in this case I'm trying to save it to a memoryStream.

```
using (MemoryStream fotoStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    Bitmap imagen = picture1.Image as Bitmap;
    imagen.Save(fotoStream, imagen.RawFormat); //Error here
    byte[] array = fotoStream.ToArray();
    fotoStream.Close();
}
```

Any light on this?

Comment: Don't apologise for us English folk :(

Comment: i think you may need to show more code. There are a number of potential problems here... But, the first thing that comes to mind: make sure that your Image as Bitmap cast doesn't evaluate to NULL

Comment: Well, like someone said, it's not a null exception. Even stranger behavior occurs: I'm loading an image from disk to the picturebox, this image is saved in the stream and the array is saved to a database, when I load the image from the database and try to save it again (without modifications) the "Generic GDI+ error" is raised. 
Strange :S

Answer (score 0):

Can you save the image in any other format, or by calling the `Save` overload that doesn't specify a format?

Have you checked the dimensions of the image to ensure that both width and height are non-zero?

Comment: I can't use an overload for saving the image because the one I'm using  is the only one that accepts a stream.

Answer (score 0):

**How are you saving it to the database?  You might want to create a test program that compares what you sent to the database and what you get back to make sure that they are the same.**

Can you give us the full stack trace of the exception?  imagen can't be null  in this case or the exception would be a null exception when trying to access .RawFormat.

What does imagen look like in the debugger?

Comment: The full stack trace:

   en System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
   en System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageFormat format)
   en SPCC.Win.Seguridad.frmUsuarios.get_Foto()
   en SPCC.MVP.Seguridad.Presenters.UsuariosPresenter.GrabarUsuario()
   ..................


But I think is something related with the RawFormat, because I'm loading the image from the database. Has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: I'm using NHibernate to save the data, it's saving and loading the image correctly, when I load the image from the database it's displayed on a picturebox correctly, the problem is when I try to save the same image loaded from the DB. The error is not raised if I load another image into the picturebox.